# How to use aws-sdk in an AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

How do I use aws-sdk in a lambda. I'm trying to follow this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/
but I cannot get `var aws = require("aws-sdk");` to work, I get an error "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead"
How come AWS’s own solution doesn't even work?

EDIT: using `import { AWS } from 'aws-sdk';` doesn't work either, I get the error "Cannot find package 'aws-sdk' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"

Comment: require function, which is a Node.js function used to load modules, in a context where it's not available. In recent versions of Node.js, which is the underlying platform used by AWS Lambda, the require function is only available when using the CommonJS module system use import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

Comment: Might help: [AWS Lambda function handler in Node.js - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)

Comment: @DarkVision doesn't work either, I get error "Cannot find package 'aws-sdk' imported from /var/task/index.mjs" when using the line `import { AWS } from 'aws-sdk';`

Comment: when you create your funtion did you specific what type runtime version of nodejs to run ?

Comment: I used Node.js 18.x. I tried switching to Node.js 14.x but it didn't work either. Nothing works and AWS's documentation is all incorrect.

Comment: this doesnt work either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74792293/aws-lambda-cannot-find-module-aws-sdk-in-build-a-basic-web-application-tutoria

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Docs are outdated and examples doesnt work. I don't know how to import aws-sdk in index.mjs of lambda function

Comment: I solved it by using `import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue. I used `import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";` instead

Answer (score 2):

As @dil12321 pointed out- apparently, the [current SDK version (3)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html#:%7E:text=In%20V3%2C%20you%20can%20load%20and%20use%20only%20the%20individual%20AWS%20Services%20you%20need.:%7E:text=In%20V3%2C%20you%20can%20load%20and%20use%20only%20the%20individual%20AWS%20Services%20you%20need.) will only allow individual services, not the whole SDK. (See the **Modularized Packages** section)

This will probably change in the future, so be sure to verify the SDK version (I was using a tutorial which is currently out of date).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const sqs = new AWS.SQS();
```

Comment: This does not work